# how to redirect 500 error to default error page for asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

i need to redirect to default error page for 500 error or for wrong url.
i tried below changes in config but it dint work

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/GenericError.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/GenericError.aspx"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/GenericError.aspx"/>
        <error statusCode="302" redirect="~/GenericError.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Here is Error snapshot : when i try to do small change in url

[image]

Comment: 500 is the http status code.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use. This also includes grabbing the exception and setting it as an application variable in case you need to relay that info, and prevents infinite loops if there is an error on the error page.

In the Global.asax file:

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Fires when an error occurs
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    // store the error for later
    Application["TheException"] = ex;
    Server.ClearError();

    if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("GenericError.aspx") == false)
        Response.Redirect("~/GenericError.aspx");
}
```

Comment: let me try this and come back to you........

Comment: i tried to use same code in my global file but it dint redirect to default err page and above snapshot appears which i attached in question.

Comment: @VimalSingh I updated it, there was a syntax issue with setting the application variable. Please let me know if it works and if a breakpoint will hit this method.

Comment: let me try it again and get back to you.......